# How to remove margins from Matplotlib bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to remove margins from Matplotlib bar chart?

[image]

Comment: Why have you added blurry screenshots of your code and the output rather than include them in the question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the limits of the axes to `-.5` and `len(df)-.5` to avoid the margins of the bar chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.rcParams["patch.force_edgecolor"] = True

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2])
df.plot.bar(width=1)
plt.xlim(-0.5,len(df)-.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Also, if you use `plt.xlim(ax.patches[0].get_x(), ax.patches[-1].get_x())` you don't need to hardcode the values.

Comment: I think with ax.patches[-1].get_x()) you miss the last bar

Comment: @Vincent Yes, it misses the last bar but it can be handled by adding the last bar's width: ```plt.xlim(ax.patches[0].get_x(), ax.patches[-1].get_x() + ax.patches[-1].get_width())
```